# unique maximum matching

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to use bipartite graph to code my program with following properties:

1. in each side, there is N vertices
2. the graph is connected

Now, I wanna add a condition in my code which check if the number of edges is bigger than **M**, do not allow user to more activities(in a simple sentence print something in that condition) where M is **maximum number edges** such that it still has a **unique** maximum matching.

The question is how can I find M?

Any idea will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment, I thought is clear, anyway I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: koja mikhoni mahdi? ki in soala ro behetoon mide?

Comment: iran nistam, soala ham hamashoon az ye ja nis, baziashon sade shodeye ghesmati az masalehaye algo han, baziashoon o ham too ye program ya project beheshoon ehtiaj peyda mikonam

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to find maximum m such that there is at least one graph with n vertices and m edges with a unique maximum matching, the answer is (n + 1) * n / 2.

to show that there is at least one graph with this number of edge, consider a graph with vertices x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, .., x<sub>n</sub> in one part and vertices y<sub>1</sub>, .. y<sub>n</sub> in another part. draw an edge between vertex x<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>j</sub> iff (i <= j).

to show there can be no more edges, use induction on the number of vertices. first of all we can show if every vertex in the graph is connected to at least two vertex, the graph has at least two different maximum matching. (consider one maximum matching, follow a path from a vertex whose edges alternates between matching edges and non-matching edges, make a circle and reverse all the edges.)

so we know there is one vertex with degree equal to one. remove this vertex and it's neighbor and use induction on the remaining graph.

sorry for bad English.